# Symfony2 - HWI/OAuthBundle can't find user provider

Tags: facebook, symfony, hwioauthbundle

Trying to connect facebook using `HWI/OAuthBundle`, following all of the steps that say in [HWI/OauthBundle Doc](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md), but it return error

> There is no user provider for user "HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\OAuthUser"

Does anyone can explain for me why this happen and how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 21):

Add to security.yml

```
providers:                             
    hwi:                               
        id: hwi_oauth.user.provider
```

or your custom user provider service

Comment: In the version 2.0 Beta2, I had to put `hwi_oauth.user.provider` instead of `hwi`, otherwise I got an `Invalid firewall "main": user provider "hwi_oauth.user.provider" not found.` exception

Answer (score 3):

Above is almost correct. It should be added to security.yml not services.yml. See below for example in context.

```
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                admin: { password: somesecretpassowrd, roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }
    hwi:                               
        id: hwi_oauth.user.provider
```

Answer (score -1):

This exception appears when `services.yml` is put below `security.yml` in `config.yml`. Apparently, hwi_oauth service has to be defined before it's going to be used in security providers. So the correct sequence of resources in `config.yml` is supposed to be:

```
 
         - { resource: services.yml }
         - { resource: security.yml }
```